# seeking a better way to code and compress numbers

Tags: c++, encoding, numbers

I have 13 numbers drawing from a set with 13 types of data, each type has 4 item so total 52 items. We can number the item as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13, so there will be 4 "1", 4"2", ... 4"13" in the set. The 13 numbers drawing from the set are random. The whole process repeated million times or even more, so I need a efficient way to store the 13 numbers. I was thinking to use some sort of coding method to compress the 13 integers into bits. For example, I count how many "1", "2" ... first, coding the count for each item with 2 bits and use 1 more bit to denote if the item was drawn or not. So for each item, we need 3 bits, total 13 items cost 39 bits. It definite need 8 bytes to do so. But it is still too much since I am talking about couple millions or billion times of calculation and each set have to be stored to the file later. So if I use 8 bytes, if will still asking about 80GB for my data. However, if I can reduce that by half, I will save 40GB. Any idea how to compress this structure more efficiently? I also think of to use 5 bytes instead but than I need to take care of the different type of number (one int + one char), is there any library in c++ can easily do the coding/compressing for me?

Thanks.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to beat the casino, eh? :-)

Comment: Is the ordering of the numbers important? Otherwise it seems the you could easily store your items as bits in a long where each bit represents if a specific item is drawn or not. For 1 million of those your need 8MB of storage. By billion, do you bean 100 million or 1 million million? For the former you would only need 8GB for storage. This could be reduced by 12.5% by using 7 bytes instead of a 8 byte long. For further compression, is there any structure to the data or is it purely random?

Comment: It is not for homework, and not project for breaking the casino. I am trying to verify a ancient Chinese chess. I am trying to find out the best way to start the game. BTW, the order of the number doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try googling LV77 and LVZ compression

Answer (score 1):

Google's Protocol Buffers can store integers with less bits, depending on its value. It might reduce your storage significantly. See http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

The actual protocol is described here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding

As for compression, have you looked at how [zlib](http://zlib.net/) handles your data?

Answer (score 1):

With your scheme, every hand of 39 bits represented by 8 bytes of 64 bits will have 25 bits wasted, about 40%.

If you batch hands together, you can represent them without wasting those bits.

39 and 64 have no common factors, so the lowest common multiple is just the multiple 39 * 64 = 2496 bits, or 312 bytes. This holds 64 hands and is about 60% of the size of your current scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit more sophisticated than you're looking for, but check out [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/).